# How to use single quotes inside single quotes

Tags: javascript

I am using the following script to insert this value **'%.1VALUE'** in single quotes. But I am unable to pass the value inside the single quotes. Anyone please help me regarding this.

```
   <td width="10px"><input type="radio" name="dis" value=""  onclick="javascript:Jmol.script(jmolApplet0,'load /ws/output/re_$file;set antialiasDisplay on;color translucent;spacefill off;wireframe off;backbone 0.05;color cpk;select $donor;label %n %r %a;select $hydpos;label %n %r %a;select $acceptor;label %n %r %a;select $donacc;center selected;color cpk;color bond dodgerblue;color label white;set labeloffset 10 0;set measurement on;set measurements 0.001;color measurements yellow;set measure angstroms;spacefill 0.4;wireframe 0.2;backbone off;move -150 50 20 300 0 0 0 0 1;color measurements [x3DFF00];set fontsize 20;$distance'%.1VALUE'; set fontsize 10;set echo top left;echo <sup>*</sup>Standard Deviation- $dpi;')" ></td>
```

That value is default command within the applet.'%.1VALUE' is used to round off the measured value in the applet

Command Usage: measure (ARG9:A.NH2)(ASP7:A.OD2)'%.1VALUE';

Consider $distance=measure (ARG9:A.NH2)(ASP7:A.OD2)

If i give the same command in console box of the applet its working Perfect. When I pass the value through the script its not executing.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: I've already tried using with escape character but there is no desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Try building the string, like this:

```
<td><input type="radio" name="dis" value="" onclick="javascript:Jmol.script(jmolApplet0,'set fontsize 20; $distance' + %.1VALUE + ';')" ></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your syntax is correct, you can use the escape character '\' to "tell" JavaScript that you are not done with the string yet, and this single quote should be inside the screen.

```
<td><input type="radio" name="dis" value="" onclick="javascript:Jmol.script(jmolApplet0,'set fontsize 20;$distance\'%.1VALUE\';')" ></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, you can *escape* characters with `\`:

```
<td>
   <input type="radio" name="dis" value="" onclick="javascript:Jmol.script(jmolApplet0,'set fontsize 20;$distance\'%.1VALUE';\')" >
</td>
```

Comment: I've already tried using with escape character but there is no desired output. –

Comment: @user3032425: It depends on what you want to achieve. How are you generating the `%.1VALUE`?

Comment: That value is default command within the applet.'%.1VALUE' is used to round off the measured value in the applet.